# On the same page, can we retrieve different values from php by using on.change function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdo, onchange

The dropdown box have different account id, I used Jquery on change function to get different account id every time I select, and then get first_name from database using that account id I selected. I couldn't get $web_account_number from javascript. $web_account_number=$_POST['web_account_number'] is empty. is there any other way I can make it works. Thanks in advance for helping me.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
require_once("connect.php"); 
echo '<body bgcolor="#F8E9CE">';

$web_account_number=$_POST['web_account_number'];
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////get dropdown web number number/////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$dsn='mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname=recipe_uploads';
try{
$dbh=new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo '<div align="center"><h1><span  style="color:#854513">Please Select Account</span><h1></div>';

$stmt2=$dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT web_account_number FROM  recipe_typist WHERE email_sent=0 AND recipes_saves=1 ORDER BY web_account_number ASC");  
        $stmt2->execute();

        $accounts2=$stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $web_account_number2=$accounts2[0]['web_account_number'];

    echo '<p><div> Send to: <select class="ui-widget select ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="email_select" style="width:140px;font-size:12px;text-align:center;color:black;margin:6px 0 6px 6px">';

        echo '<option value="View_All_Accounts" >View All Accounts</option>';
            foreach($accounts2 as $data2){
                echo '<option value="'.$data2['web_account_number'].'" >'.$data2['web_account_number'].'</option>';

    }           
        echo '</select></div></div>';

}
    catch(Exception $e){
        }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////get Email content/////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    try{
        $dsn='mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname=newsql_contact_section';
    $dbh=new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $stm=$dbh->prepare("SELECT first_name,organization,email FROM primary_contact WHERE web_account_number=:web_account_number LIMIT 1 ");
    $stm->execute(array('web_account_number'=>$web_account_number));
        $foundResult= $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $first_name=$foundResult[0]['first_name'];
        $organization=$foundResult[0]['organization'];
        $email=$foundResult[0]['email'];
        print_r($foundResult);


    }
        catch(Exception $e){
            }

    echo '<div id="name"><p>Dear: <input class="ui-widget select ui-state-default ui-corner-all"type="text" id="first_name" value="'.$first_name.'"></p></div>';





    ?>

    <script>

    $('#email_select').on('change',function(){
            web_account_number=$('#email_select').val();


        displayemail(web_account_number)


                });

   function displayemail(web_account_number){


    if(web_account_number=='View_All_Accounts'){
        loademail(web_account_number);
    }else{      
     loademail(web_account_number);
    }

    }
function loademail(web_account_number){
        //// If web_account_number is not empty the we will only load the records from that number /////
                $.ajax({
                url:'show_email.php',
                dataType:'text',
                type:'POST',
                data:{'web_account_number':web_account_number},
                success:function(result){   
                    $("#first_name").val(web_account_number);
                        },

                error:function(result){
                    }               
                });     


     } 
    </script>
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Please indent the code properly. You have missing tags and ending semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code.

- At the end of your code, you do not close the PHP with `?>`
- You have an opening `<script>` tag in your `on change` function, what is no valid there.
- You have no closing `</script>` tag at the and of the `on change` function.
- You have no `document.ready` function.
- Where is your `displayemail` javascript function?

So fix it like this, and come back if you have also errors:

```
echo '<div id="name"><p>Dear: <input class="ui-widget select ui-state-default ui-corner-all"type="text" id="first_name" value="' . $first_name . '"></p></div>';
?> <!-- ADD THIS CLOSING -->


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { //Add this 
        $('#email_select').on('change', function() {
            web_account_number = $('#email_select').val();
            displayemail(web_account_number);
        });
    });
</script> <!-- Remove the <script> inside your function and add a closing here -->
```

Comment: okay, I fixed it, but how can i get $web_account_number=$_POST['web_account_number'] I selected from dropdown box Thank you